# ¿Como ajusto el tamaño de una columna en una tabla y que el contenido de esta se ajuste al tamaño de la columna?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

La solución quizá es sencilla pero soy novato y agradecería su ayuda. Tengo una tabla dentro de un `div`, pero las columnas se ajustan al tamaño del texto y el texto no llega a dar un salto de línea, por lo que la tabla se sale del `div`, le agregue al estilo `"overflow: hidden;"` pero solo oculta la parte de la tabla que se sale del `div`.

**¿Como ajusto la tabla al tamaño del div y que el texto se ajuste al ancho de las columnas no que la columna se ajuste al texto?**

No logro que las columnas tengan un tamaño fijo de tal forma que la tabla quede del tamaño del `div` y que el texto se ajuste al tamaño que tiene la columna, que la columna solo crezca para abajo no a lo ancho.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/humns.png)

```
 <div class="container mt-4" >
  <h3>Carrito</h3>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8" style="background-color:darkseagreen; overflow: hidden;  ">
      <table class="table table-hover ">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ITEM</th>
              <th>NOMBRES</th>
              <th >DESCRIPCION</th>
              <th >PRECIO</th>
              <th >CANTIDAD</th>
              <th >SUBTOTAL</th>
              <th >ACCION</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>aaaaa</td>
              <td>bbbbb</td>
              <td>ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
              <td>dddd</td>
              <td>eeeee</td>
              <td>fffffff</td>
              <td>
                  <a href="#">eliminar</a>
                  <a href="#">editar</a>
              </td>
            </tr>

          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:rgb(138, 189, 190);>
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h3>Generar Compra</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <label>Subtotal:</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control">
          <label>Descuento:</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control">
          <label>Total a pagar:</label>
          <input type="text" readonly="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
        <!-- <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-block">Realizar Pago</a>-->
          <a href="../checkout/formulario de pago.html" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Generar Compra</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado a usar `max-width`?

Comment: Con bootstrap pordias solucionarlo de una manera muy simple, estas disouesto a utilizarlo?

Comment: si me podrian explcar como implementarlo en el código que tengo se los agradecería, si estoy usando bootstrap pero estoy aprendiendo  a usarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución es usar [`word-break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) y establecerla como `break-all`

> `break-all`
> Para evitar el desbordamiento, deben insertarse saltos de palabra entre dos caracteres cualesquiera (excluido el texto chino/japonés/coreano).

*Nota: Traducción literal*.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
td {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover ">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ITEM</th>
      <th>NOMBRES</th>
      <th>DESCRIPCION</th>
      <th>PRECIO</th>
      <th>CANTIDAD</th>
      <th>SUBTOTAL</th>
      <th>ACCION</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaaaa</td>
      <td>bbbbb</td>
      <td>ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</td>
      <td>dddd</td>
      <td>eeeee</td>
      <td>fffffff</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#">eliminar</a>
        <a href="#">editar</a>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente la solución era sencilla, al `td` le agregue el `max-width` pero aun así se desbordaba el contenido pero un poco diferente así que también le agregue `"overflow: hidden"` y problema resuelto.

```
<td style="max-width: 10px; overflow: hidden;">este texto es demasiado largo para caber el la columna</td>
```

Así quedo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Consejo no agregues los estilos CSS dentro de las tag HTML, eso no es escalable ni una buena práctica, para eso mejor dispones de clases o id para construirle su propia regla CSS

Comment: gracias por el consejo, por el momento lo tengo así por que quería encontrar la solución al problema, pero haré una clase